# Model best practices in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I've got two questions related to the best way to manage a model in an mvc project.

- Can i use a constructor for initialize my model  (obviously with its related logic)?
- For this purpose, is better to use "the constructor way", or I should use extension method called by controller after the creation of the new model instance?

For example I've a model for a contact form. User can be in three roles: anonymous, client or supplier and he can submit the form in each state. The only thing that I want is that if the user is logged in (like client's role or supplier's role) I want to preload in textboxes his datas. 
For do this I've wrote this code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using DrOkR2.Bll.Managers;

namespace DrOkR2.WebFront.Models
{

    public class RequestModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Prov { get; set; }
        public string Request { get; set; }
        public bool UsageConditions { get; set; }

        public RequestModel()
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return;
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Client"))
            {
                var guid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
                var manager = new ClientManager();
                var client = manager.GetClient(guid);
                client.Email = Membership.GetUser().Email;

                FirstName = client.FirstName;
                LastName = client.LastName;
                Email = client.Email;
                Phone = client.Phone;
                Prov = client.Prov;
            }
            else if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Supplier"))
            {
                var guid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
                var manager = new SupplierManager();
                var supplier = manager.GetSupplier(guid);
                supplier.Email = Membership.GetUser().Email;

                FirstName = supplier.FirstName;
                LastName = supplier.LastName;
                Email = supplier.Email;
                Phone = supplier.PrimaryPhone;
                Prov = supplier.BusinessProv;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly, but my question is: am I using the best possible way?

Comment: for me it makes sense, since you won't construct invalid objects.

Comment: I cannot have invalid objects. The worst thing that i can have is a user logged in with an empty contact form. The problem is:"the user login logic is right placed here or I should move in an extension method?"

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Coupling your view model with `HttpContext` makes sense to you?

Comment: @james if you read my answer, you'll see that I agree with the validation in constructor, only!

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio even at that, you think it's a good idea to have that sort of business logic inside a view model? Sorry but I vastly disagree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you should not have a dependency on `HttpContext` or any data access in your models. You're opening yourself up to all kinds of problems with model binding (not to mention tightly coupled).

Set your model properties in your Controller, or a repository that is used by your Controller.

```
public ActionResult Contact(string id)
{
   var client = _repository.GetClient(id);
   var model = new RequestModel(){ /* set your properties from client */ };

   return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is far too much business logic in your view model for my liking. You are also coupling your view model with your `HttpContext` which is not a good idea.

That sort of initialization belongs in the controller e.g.

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    ....
}

public ActionResult ContactForm(...)
{
    var contactModel = new RequestModel();  
    if (User.IsInRole("Client"))
    {
        ...
    } 
    else if (User.IsInRole("Supplier"))
    {
        ...
    }

    return View(contactModel);
}
```

Comment: Your code was my previuos solution to this problem. But my form is in a partial view not directly in a view and i need to call it from a lot of different pages. For this reason, I don't want to manage the controller logic each time.

Comment: @G10 move the logic to a business logic class and reuse it in each controller you need need it.

Comment: @G10 Partial views still need to come via some controller so you could wrap this code up in a re-usable method or even introduce a base controller and place the method in there so you have access to it system wide.

Comment: Ok, I haven't thought about problems related to using httpContext in model.

Answer (score 0):

I've realized this. For complete the thread I put it here. Any suggestion? 
Model:

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Prov { get; set; }
    public string Request { get; set; }
    public bool UsageConditions { get; set; }

    public RequestModel(DrOkUser user )
    {

        if (user == null) return;
        var type = user.GetType().Name;         //Client o Supplier
        Email = user.Email;
        if (type == "Client")
        {
            FirstName = ((Client)user).FirstName;
            LastName = ((Client)user).LastName;
            Phone = ((Client)user).Phone;
            Prov = ((Client)user).Prov;
        }
        if (type == "Supplier")
        {
            FirstName = ((Supplier)user).FirstName;
            LastName = ((Supplier)user).LastName;
            Phone = ((Supplier)user).PrimaryPhone;
            Prov = ((Supplier)user).BusinessProv;
        }
    }
}
```

the controller method:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
 public ActionResult Assistance()
    {
        var user = GetCurrentUser();
        var mdl = new RequestModel(user);
        return View(mdl);
    }
}
```

and the BaseController:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
 public DrOkUser GetCurrentUser()
    {
        if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return null;
        DrOkUser user = null;
        var guid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        if (HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Client"))
             user = ClientManager.GetClient(guid);
        if (HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Supplier"))
            user = SupplierManager.GetSupplier(guid);

        user.Email = Membership.GetUser().Email;            
        return user;
    }
```

}